# GTK page content widget

Tags: c, gtk

What is the name of the "page" widget that can be seen at the Evince Document Viewer & LibreOffice?I refer to that widget behind the text area /drawing area which looks like a sheet of paper.

Answer (score 3):

In Evince, that would be [`EvView`](http://developer.gnome.org/libevview/stable/libevview-ev-view.html).

In LibreOffice, that would be something entirely different, probably some sort of cross-platform widget.

Comment: thank you.So to be exact,the evince developers created that widget and i have to use their library?Is there any way to achieve it without using onother library except gtk?

Comment: @Nick If you don't want to use the evince team's code, you'll have to write your own just like the evince team did. You can look at libevview's code for inspiration.

Comment: The way would be to basically copy the Evince code. You will need Cairo in any case, but that's also a dependency of GTK so shouldn't add any overhead.

Comment: right.i'll take a look at the source of the library.Thank you both.

Comment: i installed libevview-dev and libevview3 from synaptic which both are version 2.32,added the package to the project,included the library using #include <libview/ev-view.h> and i get <gtk/gtk.h> no file or directory